# Is there a way to pre-populate UISearchDisplayController with results before the user starts typing in the SearchBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I would like to show past searches immediately after the search bar becomes active. but even though the datasource has these values, the search display controller doesn't call the table view methods until the user starts typing. Is there a way to force this on UISearchDisplayController?

Answer (score -1):

As long as your delegate is set up properly, you can return whatever data set you want.

```
 self.searchResults = @[@"some stuff", @"some more stuff", @"and so on..."];

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
   if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView]) {
     return [self.searchResults count];
   }
   else {
     return [self.data count];
   }
}
```

Comment: The table view will not show up until you start typing your in the search bar.